# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityInterceptor' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to sign using SOAP request and due to that, I need to use ws-security dep from Spring.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"mk.softnet.wsdl","mk.softnet.Porting"})
public class SoapConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public XwsSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() {
        XwsSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new XwsSecurityInterceptor();

        securityInterceptor.setPolicyConfiguration(new ClassPathResource("securityPolicy.xml"));
        securityInterceptor.setCallbackHandler(callbackHandler());
        //Security Policy -> securityPolicy.xml


        return securityInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler callbackHandler() {
        SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler callbackHandler = new SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler();
        // TODO @rap: Use real username and passwords
        callbackHandler.setUsersMap(Collections.singletonMap("user", "password"));
        return callbackHandler;
    }
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>mk.softnet</groupId>
    <artifactId>Porting</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Porting</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.14.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>mk.softnet.wsdl</generatePackage>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>WDSL_URL
                            </url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

### Test set: mk.softnet.Porting.PortingApplicationTests

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.79 s <<< FAILURE! - in mk.softnet.Porting.PortingApplicationTests
contextLoads(mk.softnet.Porting.PortingApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [mk/softnet/Porting/config/SoapConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor]: Factory method 'securityInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/wss/XWSSecurityException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor]: Factory method 'securityInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/wss/XWSSecurityException
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/wss/XWSSecurityException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException
```

I tried to change version but did not get any success.

Comment: Remove `version` tags from the dependencies.

Comment: I did that and it did not help. The same issue. Link to pom.xml file: https://pastebin.com/N5YWpLDK

Comment: You also need additional dependencies. You are on JDK 11 which has stuff removed which was available earlier. So you need some Sun specific dependencies probably for jax-ws extension.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `com.sun.xml.wss` dependency.

**Add this dependency to the `pom.xml`  :**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.wss</groupId>
            <artifactId>xws-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xmldsig</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.crypto</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

**Look at the pom for [spring-ws-security - 2.2.0 RELEASE](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/ws/spring-ws-security/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-ws-security-2.2.0.RELEASE.pom)**

Comment: Thank you. I know what to look for now. But I have now different issue: Failure to find javax.activation:activation:jar:1.0.2 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resoluti
on will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced